# Espresso test fails to match text of TextView

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, mockwebserver

I'm learning `Espresso` and I want to test that a `TextView` displays the string I get from the server. For server I'm using `MockWebServer`. I stored the response as a json string to assets folder inside my `androidTest` sourceSet.

The code I'm using is :

```
@Test
public void testTextViewIsShowingResult() throws Exception {
    // given
    String responseFile = "response_200_ok.json";
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setBody(TestServiceHelper.getStringFromFile(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), responseFile)));

    // when
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);

    // then
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_name)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText("square")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

Although I see the result being displayed on my screen ( I added a breakpoint at the last line of the above code ) meaning the textView displays text = "square", espresso test fails.

Logcat :

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "square"

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909227, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=63.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->ActionBarOverlayLayout{id=2131427397, res-name=decor_content_parent, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1731, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1584, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=147.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->RelativeLayout{id=2131427414, res-name=activity_main, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1584, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131427415, res-name=tv_name, visibility=VISIBLE, width=84, height=155, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=42.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>AppCompatImageView{id=2131427416, res-name=iv_avatar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=525, height=525, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=197.0}
|
+---->ActionBarContainer{id=2131427398, res-name=action_bar_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=147, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->Toolbar{id=2131427399, res-name=action_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=147, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=565, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=38.0, text=EspressoDaggerTesting, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=147, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=1080.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+----->ActionBarContextView{id=2131427400, res-name=action_context_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+->View{id=16908336, res-name=navigationBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=126, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1794.0}
|
+->View{id=16908335, res-name=statusBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=63, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at css.demo.espressodaggertesting.MainActivityTest.testTextViewIsShowingResult(MainActivityTest.java:58)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

Tests ran to completion.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. Is it my `Espresso` code wrong? I suppose `MockWebServer` code is correct since I see the results on my screen.

XML layout file :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="css.demo.espressodaggertesting.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There are two TextViews in your View Hierarchy: one with empty text and another with text=EspressoDaggerTesting

Comment: @shmakova hmm..that's not possible, I have edited the question adding my XML code.

Comment: @shmakova ohhh I see ! The one you are mentioning is the title of the toolbar.

Comment: Are you sure the string is exactly `square`? No spaces, no upper case?

Comment: @azizbekian yes I'm absolutely sure